# Write function inline (not inline function) C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function, inline

I was wondering if I could write something like a function inline, or maybe more like a block with a return statement. Here's an example of what I'm thinking:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("result is '%s'\n", 
        {
            char buffer[100];
            //Do some code here to determine string
            return buffer;
        }
    )

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: Choose C or C++. Those are different languages with different solutions.

Comment: @BaummitAugen it seems like we already have the C++ solution, from NathanOliver. If there is one for C, that would be nice as well.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen That's a different question, because c isn't c++ isn't c.

Comment: Why do you want this? Why not use an inline function?

Comment: @Ben so that I have access to local variables for one. Also, if I'm never going to use that function again, it's just more convenient.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen Then why even have a function? Just put the code you want there?

Comment: @Ben look at the example above. With something like a lambda, I could embed code into arguments for another function, for instance. Or a C++ stream. It just seems easier to me. Not to mention that scoped variables would be destroyed easily.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen For future questions: Please make sure to choose the right **language** when asking a question. C and C++ are **different** programming languages, with different idioms and good practices. A question which does not make clear which programming language it is about is not a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking is [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

*Note* that lambda functions have been introduced since *C++11*, so you should have a compatible compiler (almost all recent compiler support them, nowadays).

This is just a little example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Define a closure - note use 'auto' in order to auto-determine the type.
  auto my_lambda = []() -> std::string {
    return std::string("This is a string");
  };

  std::cout << "Result: " << my_lambda() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

*Additional notes:* this is C++. C does not have that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The standard C solution for this is to write procedural, not "functional" code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buffer[100];
    {
       // some code, note that variables here go out of scope at the next }
    }
    printf("result is '%s'\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

You can use `{ /* ... */ }` to introduce nested scopes, even inside functions.

*Note that the code you showed would - even if there's something like lambdas - cause undefined behavior because you're returning a pointer to a no more existing array (it has gone out of scope).*

If that `// some code ...` is a lot, then you put it into a separate function, and mark it as `static` so that it's not exported from the translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

GCC supports nested functions as an extention, but it's *not* portable/standard.

Alternatively you can use a lambda.